# How do I Create Electron App from existing React Project without disturbing the React Project

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have existing React Apps which are published to production web servers but I want to run them from the desktop using Electron. However, I do not want to disturb the React App package.json. I attempted to decouple an existing online tutorial by paachu on Medium but was unsuccessful. It kept failing trying to locate "main...chunk.css" and other resources needed by the React App.

With that said, I have a working React App in directory ./projx/reactApp I would like to create an Electron App in ./projx/electronApp that will build and create a packaged executable using electron-builder. The dev environment is not necessary at this time in that I only need a release package to distribute. Here is a package.json that almost works:

```
{
  "name": "wrappedReact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/electron.js",
  "scripts": {
    "preclean": "cross-env rm -rf build",
    "react-prebuild": "cross-env cp -r ../reactApp/build build",
    "build-tsapp": "tsc ./src/electron.ts",
    "electron-prebuild": "mv ./src/*.js ../build",
    "electron-build": "npm run electron-prebuild && electron-builder",
    "build": "npm run preclean && npm run electron-build",
    "startdev": "concurrently \"tsc ./src/electron.ts -w\"  \"cross-env 
       NODE_ENV=dev nodemon --exec \"\"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && 
       electron src/electron.js\"\""
 },
 "author": "sfanjoy",
 "homepage": "./",
 "electron-pack": "build --em.main=build/electron.js",
 "build": {
   "appId": "com.example.reactApp",
   "productName": "ReactApp",
   "copyright": "Copyright © 2019 sfanjoy",
   "files": [
     "build/**/*",
     "node_modules/**/*"
   ],
   "directories": {
     "buildResources": "assets"
   },
   "win": {
     "target": "portable",
     "icon": "assets/app.ico"
  }
},
"dependencies": {
  "@types/electron": "^1.6.10"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/electron": "^1.6.10",
  "concurrently": "^4.1.1",
  "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
  "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
  "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
  "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
  "typescript": "^3.5.2",
  "wait-on": "^3.2.0"
 }
}
```

I think the solution is with electron-builder if it would allow you to inject the ./src/electron.js into the prebuilt   reactApp\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar. I could then copy the reactApp/build directory, inject into the asar, and call electron-builder.

This by far (IMO) is the best starting setup (Boilerplate) I have come accross:
https://github.com/nateshmbhat/electron-react-ts-starter/

Comment: have you found any solution to this?

Comment: No solution ever found.